# if last value is equal to `value` in while loop

Tags: python, dataframe, while-loop, python-asyncio

I have a coroutine triggered by a while loop and a DataFrame updated each second:

```py
_lock = asyncio.Lock()

while True:
    df = # DataFrame is updated with a new entry
    asyncio.run(coroutine())
    time.sleep(1)

async def coroutine():
    if cond1:
        await _lock.acquire()
        time.sleep(.5)
        # wait until cond2 is True
        _lock.release()
```

the `cond2` is about a shared ressource: say, `if df.iloc[-1] == value`. I want that `df.iloc[-1]` in `cond2` be updated while on Lock. "If the last value is equal to another value"

I tried to add a counter for index, but when lock is acquired, the loop is still.

---

I have below a minimal reproducible case:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import threading
import asyncio

class Thread1(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        global _download
        _download = {}

    def run(self):
        ind_df = pd.DataFrame(...) # any DataFrame
        data = self.get_data(ind_df)
        count = 0

        while True:
            _download[count] = next(data).values
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(_download, orient='index', columns=...) #columns of ind_df
            time.sleep(.5)
            count += 1    

    def get_data(self, df):
        i = 0
        while i < df.shape[0]:
            yield df.iloc[i]
            i += 1



class Thread2(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)

    def run(self):
        while True:
            df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(_download, orient='index', columns=...) #columns of ind_df
            asyncio.run(self.apply_coroutines(df))
            time.sleep(1)

    async def apply_coroutines(self, df):
        await asyncio.gather(
            coroutine1(),
            coroutine2(),
        )

    async def coroutine1(self):
        flag = np.random.rand(1)[0]
        if flag > .5:
            print(df.iloc[-1])
            ##########################################
            # WAIT until the last flag == .6 (example)
            ##########################################
        else:
            pass

    async def coroutine2(self):
        print('coroutine 2')
        await asyncio.sleep(.5)
```

We'll have to:

```py
t = Thread1()
t.start()
s = Thread2()
s.start()
```

I didn't bother here with threads to join. I normally use a global boolean flag to break while loops, then wait for threads.

I am lost with the condition part. Thank you in advance.

Comment: The point of a lock is to prevent other tasks from executing. Why do you acquire a lock when you are waiting for the other task to do something?

Comment: I have other coroutines and want that one of them acquire the Lock. Can't the `cond2` keep refreshing when other coroutines are blocked?

Comment: It is not really clear what your setup is, which task is updating what etc. Please create a [mcve] so that the problem can be understood.

Comment: No other coroutine can acquire the lock and actually do anything, because as soon as `coroutine` acquires it makes a blocking call to `time.sleep`.  Do you mean to write `await asyncio.sleep(0.5)` instead?  In any case, your while True: loop runs the tasks one at a time and there are no other threads, so there is no place for any code to update df.ilock[-1].

Comment: updating data-frames like this is definitely not a good idea - they are even removing the append method due to its low performance, as many times it will require all DF data to be copied around.

Comment: I was simulating the case where a server gives a  new data per minute. so dataframe catches the new data and refreshes.